# Как установить php5.6 на debian 9 (stretch)

Tags: php, linux, debian, администрирование

Проблема заключается в том что php5.6 уже считается устаревшей версией и в комплекте с ОС идёт php7.0, так как некоторые сервисы зависят от php5.6, мне нужно установить php5.6
Репозиторий https://packages.sury.org/ и ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ не помогли, они не поддерживаются уже. Соответственно как установить php5.6? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Установи в докер https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/5.6-apache/images/sha256-24c791995c1e498255393db857040793a7a040fa0f8ddd4bbe8fb230648e37d7?context=explore .

Установить в систему нормально эту версию не сможешь